# Windows closes Tkinter mainloop direct

Tags: windows, tkinter, exit

Somehow windows close my python application directly when it starts. I've walked down all the way to the basic:

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

win.mainloop()
```

I've tired to disable my virus protection in windows, tried run it from windows cmd, from githubs terminal, from python terminal. run it from the desktop as an administrator,

Comment: Do you get a tkinter window by executing `python -m tkinter`?  If not, there may be something wrong on the Python installation.

Comment: Hi, i get the window and it quits right away. I troubleshooted this for hours but i decided to go on and learn. i watched a youtube video regarding merging PDFs and he used the builtin python cmd in sublimetext and exicuted. when i did that i got some error text from whole other project document. i delited that document and boom, it worked, i now got the window! strange how the other cmds didnt give me that message.